# how to throw user friendly error message if validation fails for query params in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing an API in Django, and the URL is something like
foo.com/api/places?city_id=123
So, here my query_param is city_id, and my API should accept integers only, if query_param is sent as city_id="xyz", then my API needs to send some user-friendly message instead of 500.
May I know how to achieve that in Django, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

**Method 1**

You can send response with error code like this

```
if not request.query_params.get('city_id').isdigit():
    return Response({'message': 'Your message here'}, status=your_error_code_here)
```

**Method 2**

You can make a serializer for query param validation.

```
class ParamValidationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    city_id = serializers.IntegerField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Your message here'})
```